# Securing a docker registry with basic auth for push requests only

Tags: docker, authentication, nginx, registry

I am trying to set up a private docker registry behind an nginx proxy that is read-only (i.e. allows pull requests) for everyone but requires authentication for push requests. I have followed various guides but am still stumped. Below is my current nginx configuration:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  upstream docker-registry {
    server registry:5000;
  }

  ## Set a variable to help us decide if we need to add the
  ## 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version' header.
  ## The registry always sets this header.
  ## In the case of nginx performing auth, the header is unset
  ## since nginx is auth-ing before proxying.
  map $upstream_http_docker_distribution_api_version $docker_distribution_api_version {
    'registry/2.0' '';
    default registry/2.0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name docker-host.example.com;

    location / {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ https://docker-host.example.com$1 last;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name docker-host.example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/example.cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH::!EECDH+aRSA+RC4:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS';
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
      limit_except GET HEAD OPTIONS {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/users.pwd;
      }
      include proxy.conf;
    }
  }
}
```

It does allow anonymous pull requests but push always fails with 'unauthorized: authentication required'. If I remove the conditional `limit_except`, i.e. require authentication for all access, it works just fine after logging in.

When I remove the authentication configuration from `nginx` entirely, everything works as well, but obviously without authentication.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that `unauthorized` error generated by `registry` or `nginx`? Did you disable auth in `registry`?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that `registry` is not set-up with any authentication. When I remove the authentication config entirely from the `nginx` config, it also works. This seems to indicate that the error comes from `nginx`

Answer (score 1):

We have been using https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth and it works pretty well you can setup many authentication methods

For more info check
https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Let me know if you need some example

Comment: Took me a while to figure it all out since I wanted to run `registry` behind `traefik` (transparent proxy), but I did manage to configure `docker_auth` to do just what I wanted. Thank you very much for the pointer!

Comment: Good to hear that, it's a good project please give it a start if you can ;-) have a good day!

Answer (score -2):

"unauthorized: authentication required" error comes from registry API. that means you have auth enabled in registry's itself. either disable auth in registry and use nginx basic auth only, or proxy pass "Authorization" header with related data (tricky).

Comment: I edited the original to clarify that that is probably not the case.